# Send current record id to pop up visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I created a custom button that pops up a visualforce page on click. I need the id of the current record I clicked the button on.

```
public with sharing class AddAccountsToOppController {

  // the soql without the order and limit
  private String soql {get;set;}
  // the collection of accounts to display
  public List<aAccount> accounts {get;set;}

  public List<aAccount> accountList {get;set;}

  public Id currentOppId{get; set;}


 // init the controller and display some sample data when the page loads
  public AddAccountsToOppController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    currentOppId = controller.getId();
    System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>> ' + currentOppId);
    soql = 'select Name, Parent.Name, BillingState, BillingCity, Near_Site_Opportunity__r.Id FROM Account';
    runQuery();
  }

  public class aAccount {
    public Account acc {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}

    public aAccount(Account a) {
        acc = a;
        selected = false;
    }  
 }


  public PageReference proccessSelected() {
    List<Account> selectedAccounts = new List<Account>();


      if(accountList == null) {
          accountList = new List<aAccount>();
          for(Account a : Database.query(soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 20')) {
              accountList.add(new aAccount(a));
          }
      }


      for(aAccount aAcc : accountList) {
          if(aAcc.selected == true) {
              selectedAccounts.add(aAcc.acc);
          }
      }  
      System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>> ' + selectedAccounts);
      System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>> ' + currentOppId);
      for(Account a : selectedAccounts) {
          a.Near_Site_Opportunity__r.Id = currentOppId;
      }

      update selectedAccounts;

      selectedAccounts=null;
      return null;
  }

  // the current sort direction. defaults to asc
  public String sortDir {
    get  { if (sortDir == null) {  sortDir = 'asc'; } return sortDir;  }
    set;
  }

  // the current field to sort by. defaults to name
  public String sortField {
    get  { if (sortField == null) {sortField = 'name'; } return sortField;  }
    set;
  }

  // format the soql for display on the visualforce page
  public String debugSoql {
    get { return soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 20 ' + currentOppId; }
    set;
  }



  // toggles the sorting of query from asc<-->desc
  public void toggleSort() {
    // simply toggle the direction
    sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    // run the query again
    runQuery();
  }

  // runs the actual query
  public void runQuery() {

    try {

          accountList = new List<aAccount>();
          for(Account a : Database.query(soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 20')) {
              accountList.add(new aAccount(a));
          }

      accounts = accountList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Ooops!'));
    }

  }

  // runs the search with parameters passed via Javascript
  public PageReference runSearch() {

    String accountName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accountName');

    soql = 'select Name, Parent.Name, BillingCity, BillingState, Near_Site_Opportunity__r.Id FROM Account';

    if (!accountName.equals(''))
      soql += ' WHERE Name LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(accountName)+'%\''; 

    // run the query again
    runQuery();

    return null;
  }



}
```

For some reason I get this. The currentOppId is returning null

[image]

Visualforce code

```
 <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="AddAccountsToOppController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">

  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageMessages id="errors" />

  <apex:pageBlock title="Add Account(s)" mode="edit">

  <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>  
  <td width="200" valign="top">

  <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters" mode="edit" id="criteria">

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function doSearch() {
      var searchText = document.getElementById("accountName").value;
      if(searchText.length > 2) {
    searchServer(
      document.getElementById("accountName").value
      );
          }
  }
  </script> 

  <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results,debug,errors">
      <apex:param name="accountName" value="" />
  </apex:actionFunction>

  <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Account Name<br/>
    <input type="text" id="accountName" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Add Selected Account(s)" action="{!proccessSelected}"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  </apex:pageBlock>

</td>
<td valign="top">

<apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="results">

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="account">
        <apex:column>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!account.selected}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:commandLink value="Account Name" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                    <apex:param name="sortField" value="accountName" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!account.acc.Name}"/>
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:commandLink value="Parent Account" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                    <apex:param name="sortField" value="" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!account.acc.Parent.Name}"/>
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:commandLink value="State" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                    <apex:param name="sortField" value="" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!account.acc.BillingState}"/>
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:commandLink value="City" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                    <apex:param name="sortField" value="" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!account.acc.BillingCity}"/>
        </apex:column>

    </apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

<apex:pageBlock title="Debug - SOQL" id="debug">
  <apex:outputText value="{!debugSoql}" />           
</apex:pageBlock>    

 </apex:pageBlock>

 </apex:form>

 </apex:page>
```

Debug log screenshots

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you open your page with baseUrl/apex/yourpage?id=00xxxxxxxxxxxxx ? Does it work as expected?

Comment: Can we see the VF code? It sounds like the VF page is looking for something not available in the controller.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham added vf code

Comment: @Tyler, try c.cs14.visual.force.com/apex/AddAccountsToOpp?id=006c000000FAKU‌​K

Comment: @IlyaLepesh Thank you, I get the same "Method not found"

Comment: Where is the method in your controller for proccessSelected()?

Comment: @JeremyNottingham added it

Comment: Is runSearch() in the controller as well?

Comment: Did you not define a `runSearch` method in your controller or did you just omit it for brevity?

Comment: Sorry guys, I just added the whole controller. I tried to avoid it cause the formatting is a pain to copy and paste it.

Comment: Do you get any compile errors when you try to save the VF page?

Comment: @JeremyNottingham you know... when I add ApexPages.StandardSetController controller to my initializer and re-save my VF page, I get "Unknown constructor 'AddAccountsToOppConroller.AddAccountsToOppConroller()" in my developer console.

Comment: @Tyler are you aware you can select a whole block and just hit `CTRL + K`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson no I wasn't. Wow using stack exchange just got a whole lot easier! ha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you will need to change the page definition from

```
<apex:page controller="AddAccountsToOppConroller" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
```

to

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="AddAccountsToOppConroller" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
```

Reason being is that you are currently attempting to use a controller that only has an instantiation using the standard controller as a parameter. Changing that while to updating the page essentially invalidates the page's instantiation attempt of the controller

You must be doing something in the controller or the code is not as you posted in your question. Below is the most basic example of how it works and anything you do beyond that that breaks it you will need to investigate:

Class

```
public class exampleController{

    public Id theId {get;set;}


    public exampleController(ApexPages.standardController con){

        theId = con.getId();

    }


}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="exampleController">

    {!theId}

</apex:page>
```

Custom button on Opp detail page

Note: you could simply select the VF Option and pick the page

```
/apex/examplePage?id={!Opportunity.Id}
```

Comment: Okay the error went way, but the currentOppId is still returning null

Comment: @TylerZika - Is your constructor `public AddAccountsToOppController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {`

Comment: @Erice StandardController

Comment: something like this so i get the current opp id?  currentOppId = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord().id;

Comment: No, to get the id would be `Id i = controller.getId();` to get the opportunity it would be `Opportunity o = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();`

Comment: Still returns null.

Comment: What is the url that you are using for the popup

Comment: /apex/AddAccountsToOpp

Comment: Well, you are missing the id it should be `/apex/AddAccountsToOpp?id=xxxxx`

Comment: There is a way to dynamically add it?

Comment: Yes, using merge fields and this is all basic stuff that is well documented. I suggest you do a bit of reading on the fundamentals

Comment: I did this /apex/AddAccountsToOpp?={!Opportunity.Id} still returns null

Comment: and this /apex/AddAccountsToOpp?id={!Opportunity.Id}

Comment: Last one should work so you are doing something else wrong or not understanding the debug log

Comment: The button is on Opportunity right? Try the page by itself with a valid Opportunity ID `baseUrl/apex/yourpage?id=006xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Yes it's on an opportunity when clicked. I added screenshots of the debug log

Comment: The page appears, but currentOppId still returns null

Comment: See updated answer. You will have to work through your code removing everything till you get down to what is in the answer and then start adding code back in to see where it breaks

Comment: So you marked correct - what was your issue?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. It just started working... I've been staring at this problem for 3+ hours. Your solution to make it an extension did it for sure.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44820/discussion-on-answer-by-eric-send-current-record-id-to-pop-up-visualforce-page).